# SQL intersect two timestamp pairs and group up by hours

Tags: sql, vertica

I have A little problem.

I have A table lets call it "events" with columns like: type, (1 or 0) , timestamp start , timestamp end.

I want to group them by hours (60 minutes periods) 
Into 4 columns each calculating

1. How many minutes per hour there was no either type 1 or type 0 event.
2. How many minutes per hour there was an event type 1 and in the same time there was not event of type 2.
3. How many minutes per hour there was an event type 2 and in the same time there was no event of type 1
4. How many minutes per hour there was an event 2 and event 1 at the same time.

Result should look like this:

hour 00 10 01 11

12  10 20 20 10

13   5 15 25  15

Each row should always sum to 60 minutes.

Is it possible to do it in SQL? I need it in vertica so I can use verticas functions too.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question!  Here is a query which gets you what you need.  I mocked up the following table and some dummy data, and then showed the results from the query at the end.  As you required - the totals always add up to 60 minutes within each hour.

SETUP:

```
create table public.time_event_test(event_timestamp timestamptz, event_type int);

insert into public.time_event_test(event_timestamp,event_type) select getutcdate() as event_timestamp, 1 as event_type;
insert into public.time_event_test(event_timestamp,event_type) select TIMESTAMPADD('minute',5,getutcdate()) as event_timestamp, 1 as event_type;
insert into public.time_event_test(event_timestamp,event_type) select TIMESTAMPADD('minute',1,getutcdate()) as event_timestamp, 1 as event_type;
insert into public.time_event_test(event_timestamp,event_type) select TIMESTAMPADD('minute',1,getutcdate()) as event_timestamp, 2 as event_type;
insert into public.time_event_test(event_timestamp,event_type) select TIMESTAMPADD('minute',3,getutcdate()) as event_timestamp, 2 as event_type;
insert into public.time_event_test(event_timestamp,event_type) select TIMESTAMPADD('minute',6,getutcdate()) as event_timestamp, 2 as event_type;
insert into public.time_event_test(event_timestamp,event_type) select TIMESTAMPADD('minute',90,getutcdate()) as event_timestamp, 2 as event_type;
```

QUERY:

```
select date_trunc('hour',dat) as hr
, 60 - sum(case when event_type1 = 1 or event_type2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as type_00
, sum(case when event_type1 = 0 and event_type2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as type_01
, sum(case when event_type1 = 1 and event_type2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as type_10
, sum(case when event_type1 = 1 and event_type2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as type_11
from (
select date_trunc('minute',event_timestamp) as dat
, max(case when event_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as event_type1
, max(case when event_type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as event_type2
from public.time_event_test
group by 1
) x
group by 1 order by 1;
```

RESULTS:

```
           hr           | type_00 | type_01 | type_10 | type_11
------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------
 2016-12-21 01:00:00+00 |      52 |       3 |       2 |       3
 2016-12-21 02:00:00+00 |      59 |       1 |       0 |       0
```